# What is the advantage of wrapping the current HttpContext in an HttpContextWrapper2 object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I heard the following sentence while explaining the request Life Cycle of MVC.

> When the UrlRoutingModule intercepts a request, the first thing the
>   module does is to wrap up the current HttpContext in an
>   HttpContextWrapper2 object.

What is the significance of wrapping the HttpContext ?

> The module passes the wrapped HttpContext to the RouteTable. The
>   HttpContext includes the URL, form parameters, query string
>   parameters, and cookies associated with the current request. If a
>   match can be made between the current request and one of the Route
>   objects in the Route Table, then a RouteData object is returned.
>
> If the UrlRoutingModule successfully retrieves a RouteData object then
>   the module next creates a RouteContext object

what is the meaning of RouteContext?

I searched a lot on google but could not found any reference.

Comment: Is it a public class? If no, then it is an implementation detail. While the question itself may be interesting, what are you going to do with the answer? Anyway I can guess @DarinDimitrov's answer: _"Because the wrapper provides in additional functionality the `HttpContext` class doesn't offer"_.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the main reason is to facilitate unit testing.

`HttpContextWrapper2` inherits from `HttpContextBase` which is an abstract class with the same members as `HttpContext`.  MVC Types expose properties as `HttpContextBase` rather than `HttpContext` (e.g. [Controller.HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext(v=vs.108).aspx))) and this means that unit testing can use a concrete derived class that runs outside the ASP.NET pipeline, facilitating unit testing.

> Can you give a code example or any link ?

From [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942838.aspx) on unit testing MVC:

> In traditional ASP.NET, one of the obstacles that developers come across during testing is the plethora of static classes used during each request. The ASP.NET MVC team made the decision to wrap many of the .NET static helper classes (such as HttpContext and HttpRequest) so that they can be replaced during testing with a stub. ASP.NET MVC provides many abstractions to help developers avoid using these classes, but in places where you are required to use them, the wrappers make this code easier to test.

The ASP.NET MVC documentation is a bit thin on the ground, for a deep understanding I'd recommend the book "Pro ASP.NET MVC4 Framework".

Comment: [This link](http://volaresystems.com/blog/post/dont-mock-httpcontext.aspx) doesn't specifically help with your question, but I believe it helps illustrate the sorts of issues that this answer is alluding to avoiding when it says "facilitate unit testing"

Comment: Can you explain the Paragraph 1 once again ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would [cite the source](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/03/18/asp-net-mvc-in-depth-the-life-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request.aspx) you've got the sentence from:

> When the UrlRoutingModule intercepts a request, the first thing the module does is to wrap up the current HttpContext in an HttpContextWrapper2 object. **The HttpContextWrapper2 class, unlike the normal HttpContext class, derives from the HttpContextBase class. Creating a wrapper for HttpContext makes it easier to mock the class when you are using a Mock Object Framework such as Typemock Isolator or Rhino Mocks.**